# Vector multiplication using MATMUL in Fortran

Tags: arrays, vector, matrix, fortran, multiplication

I am trying to multiply part of a column vector (n,1) by a part of another row vector (1,n). Both parts have the same length. So I should get a matrix (n,n).

Here is my simple code:

```
PROGRAM test_pack_1
REAL :: m(1,10), x(10,1), y(10,10)

m = reshape( (/ 1, -1, 3, 2, 1, 2, -2, -2, 1, 0 /), (/ 1, 10 /))
x = reshape( (/ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 /), (/ 10, 1 /))

y(1:9,1:9) = MATMUL(x(1:9,1),m(1,1:9))


DO j = 1,10
PRINT* ;WRITE(*,*) y(:,j)
ENDDO
print *

END PROGRAM
```

I'm Using:

```
ifort -g -debug -traceback -check all -ftrapuv test_cshift.f90
```

And I'm getting:

```
test_cshift.f90(7): error #6241: The shapes of the arguments are inconsistent or nonconformable.   [MATMUL]
y(1:9,1:9) = MATMUL(x(1:9,1),m(1,1:9))
-------------^
test_cshift.f90(7): error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [Y]
y(1:9,1:9) = MATMUL(x(1:9,1),m(1,1:9))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `x(1:9,1)` isn't of shape `[9 1]` but `[9]`.  You need to use `x(1:9, 1:1)`.  The same goes for `m`.

Comment: Thanks. What about v*vT (two vectors that produce a matrix)?

Comment: One can't use `matmul` to multiply two rank-1 arrays (regardless of whether one represents a row vector and the other a column), but you can see related things in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44331867/3157076).

Comment: Thank you, I did find a solution (which is also covered in the answers you pointed out).