# The shapes of the arguments are inconsistent in CSHIFT

Tags: fortran

I'm having trouble performing the following shift of a 4-D array.
The program displays: `The shapes of the arguments are inconsistent or non - conformable.`

The dimensions of `fin` and `fout`:

```
fin (1:15,1:3,1:3,1:3)
fout (1:15,1:3,1:3,1:3)

exlD3 = (/ 0 , 1 , 0 , -1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1 /)
eylD3 = (/ 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , -1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1 /) 
ezlD3 = (/ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , -1 , 1 , -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1 /)

do k = 1,q
    cshiftx = exlD3(k)
    cshifty = eylD3(k)
    cshiftz = ezlD3(k)
    fin(k,:,:,:) = cshift( fout(k,:,:,:), SHIFT = (/0, cshifty, cshiftx, cshiftz/) )
end do
```

Comment: Welcome. We don't put any greetings or "Thanks in advance" to our posts. The title should not just introduce the topic (tags are for that) but describe your problem.

Comment: `fout(k,:,:,:)` isn't a rank-4 array.  If that is your problem, then see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22305554) for more detail.